# Backbone model remains unchanged even the object is modified in backend

Tags: spring, backbone.js

I have a backbone model. I add the following attributes to the model

```
   model.set('x',x);
   model.set('y',y);
   model.set('z',z);
```

and than i call model.save....

In the backend what i do is i set some more properties to brandDTO

But what i see is that the error attribute is not there in the error callback model

```
 app.Model.BrandModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
               url : '/brand/cu'
             });
             var brand = new app.Model.BrandModel();
     brand.save(null, {
                success : function(model, response) {
                },
                error : function(model, response) {
                            }

         });



@RequestMapping(value = "/brand/cu", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public BrandDTO createBrand(@RequestBody BrandDTO brandDTO,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

 brandDTO.setErro("error", error)
```

This error field is not there in the error callback model..
I am not sure if i am thinking right....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking right, just need to arrange this both on client and server.
I see you are using Java, is this SpringMvc?

First, you should serialize your response:

On server:

1.)Create an object/class called SerializedResponse which has "data", "success", "exception" properties.

2.)Then you can wrap a try{}catch{} on the create brand business logic, and if it succeeded set the "success" to true, if it failed to "false", if theres an exception, put it in the exception object.

Note that even if you have an error in your logic, you will always get success, as long as the operation was performed and you have recieved a response, and unless the http status code is not 200, this is handled by the jqXhr object so you can handle the callbacks from there, meaning:

```
success : function(model, response) {
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  if(data.success){
   //ALL OK     
     }   
  else {
   //Fail
    }
  }, 
  error: function(){
  //Error 
  }
```